# Syncronization inside the same PC

Tags: windows-7, synchronization

I work in a company without a server and operating in diferent countries. Because of this we work on a virtual office basis and share files through a virtual server called Drop Box. I'm the controller of this virtual server and find it to be incomplete.
We work on levels of permission so I invite access to users for 3 possible levels and find sometimes that I need to have a specific folder inside one mother folder to be inside 2 levels.
The only way I can find to make my life easier is to automatically syncronize specific folders between diferent mother folders, but I don't know how to do this in windows 7. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fast and easy way to do this would be to create some symlinks. Simply make the folder in one of your "mother" folders, then link it in the other, or if you have a very dynamic structure, create all dirs on a flat structure and link from your access "mother" folders.

I'll leave the explanation up to this [article](http://www.tested.com/news/using-symlinks-in-windows-for-fun-and-profit/39/). Google it for loads more explanations.

GLHF